# API rate limit error in using org.kohsuke.github.GHUserSearchBuilder

Tags: java, github, authorization, github-api, rate-limiting

My method looks so:

```
static void search() throws IOException {

    GitHub gitHub = GitHubBuilder
            .fromEnvironment()
            .withPassword(MyAuthData.LOGIN,MyAuthData.PASSWORD)
            .withRateLimitHandler(RateLimitHandler.WAIT)
            .build();

    GHUserSearchBuilder searchBuilder =   gitHub.searchUsers().language("Russian").location("Moscow");
    List<GHUser> users = searchBuilder.list().asList();
    for(GHUser user: users){
        System.out.println(user.getName()+" "+user.getEmail()+" "+user.getCompany());}
    System.out.println("Total: "+searchBuilder.list().getTotalCount());
}
```

And that is my log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: {"message":"API rate limit exceeded for alexey-semenov.","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"}
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$1.fetch(Requester.java:399)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$1.hasNext(Requester.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.github.PagedSearchIterable$1.hasNext(PagedSearchIterable.java:49)
    at org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterator.fetch(PagedIterator.java:44)
    at org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterator.hasNext(PagedIterator.java:32)
    at org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterable.asList(PagedIterable.java:21)
    at com.company.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:34)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: {"message":"API rate limit exceeded for alexey-semenov.","documentation_url":"httpss://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"}
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.handleApiError(Requester.java:506)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$1.fetch(Requester.java:395)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.github.com/search/users?q=language%3ARussian+location%3AMoscow&page=31
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:461)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.access$300(Requester.java:64)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$1.fetch(Requester.java:390)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: httpss://api.github.com/search/users?q=language%3ARussian+location%3AMoscow&page=31
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:457)
    ... 14 more
```

Who faced with something similar? How to do coorect authorization here?

Answer (score 1):

You're authenticating correctly -- notice that the API replied with this message:

> API rate limit exceeded for alexey-semenov

That means that [authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) was successful (because your account was recognized), but you [stepped over the rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) which is 5000 reqs/hour (per user). If you hadn't authenticated correctly, the message would have been something like this:

> API rate limit exceeded for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)

Comment: If this doesn't help, feel free to reach out via https://github.com/contact and we can probably look at our logs to let you know which endpoints you've been hitting, which might help you figure out why you're stepping over the rate limit.